# Disable notifications

Tags: notification, task-notifications

Is there a way to disable notifications bell? I have gone to setup -> user interface -> clicked user Interface and disabled Enable Salesforce Notification Banner checkbox. But still i get notifications. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Enable Salesforce Notification Banner` is a Global banner (rectangle) that shows in all pages that usually displays Salesforce communications.

What you are looking for is the App Notifications: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/s1_admin_guide_notifications.htm

Setup --> Apps --> Mobile Apps --> Salesforce --> Salesforce Notifications

[image]

Comment: Awesome man, Thanks!